# VBA '1004' error at ActiveWorkbook.Save

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have created a VBA module that :

- searches for a specific email in outlook
- grabs the excel file attachment from the email it finds
- formats the excel file attachment (adds colors and grid to make it look more presentable)
- saves the formatted excel file to my desktop
- sends email(s) to our client with the formatted excel file as an attachment (and pastes the excel file into the body of the email)

** I use multiple arrays to send to individual clients

My code works pretty well and has worked without issues many times. However, every now and again it will have a '1004 run time error' pop up randomly while processing. When I debug, it takes me to 'ActiveWorkbook.Save'. Usually if I run it again it works just fine, but I need it to be more user friendly for others to use. Code is as follows.

```
Public f As Integer 'format integer

Sub Clients()

'Array([file destination to be saved], [subject of file being searched in outlook], [file name given when saved], [emails the report is going to])

f = 0

email_1 = Array("C:\User\Desktop\", "FL Test Results", "FL_Reports", "client1@email.com")
Call Reports(email_1)

f = 1

email_2 = Array("C:\User\Desktop\", "CA Test Results", "CA_Reports", "client2@email.com")
Call Reports(email_2)

f = 2

email_3 = Array("C:\User\Desktop\", "NY Test Results", "NY_Reports", "client3@email.com")
Call Reports(email_3)

email_4 = Array("C:\User\Desktop\", "TX Test Results", "TX_Reports", "client4@email.com")
Call Reports(email_4)


End Sub

Function Reports(a As Variant)

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim olFldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Items
Dim olMi As MailItem
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Attachment


Dim subj As String
Dim saveAs As String
Dim emails As String
Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = a(0)
subj = a(1)
saveAs = a(2)
emails = a(3)

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items
Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Set olMi = olItms.Find("[Subject] = " & Chr(34) & subj & Chr(34))
  If Not (olMi Is Nothing) Then
             For Each olAtt In olMi.Attachments

                 olAtt.SaveAsFile FilePath & saveAs & ".xls"

                 Workbooks.Open (FilePath & saveAs & ".xls")

                 Call format.Run   'Seperate file that formats the raw excel sheet to look more pretty

                 If f = 0 Then

                 Call format.DeleteOldClasses    'different ways clients want there excel file info sorted

                 ElseIf f = 1 Then

                 Call format.sortByDate

                 Else

                 End If

                  ActiveWorkbook.Save '#######This is where the error pops up

                 Set rng = Worksheets(saveAs).UsedRange
             Next olAtt
End If
On Error Resume Next

With OutMail

    .Attachments.Add FilePath & saveAs & ".xls"
    .To = emails
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .subject = subj
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Kill (FilePath & saveAs & ".xls")
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olAtt = Nothing
    Set olMi = Nothing
    Set olFldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Function


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: `Set` your workbooks?

Comment: As suggested by @findwindow, declare a variable `Dim wB as Workbook` and then set that variable when you open the workbook `Set wB = Workbooks.Open(....)`, after that you can save it with `wB.Save` and close it `wB.Close`

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will implement your suggestion. I wont know if it works till tomorrow since I don't want to spam our clients with multiple emails.

Comment: Just tried it this morning and it still ran into the error. Still stops at the same spot for the same reason. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution that works for me but maybe not others with the same issue. I Set my workbooks as @findwidow and @R3uk suggested. I simply put "On Error Resume Next" and save an extra copy in a new place that I pull the attachment from to place in the email.

```
                 On Error Resume Next
                 wB.Save

                 wB.SaveCopyAs ("C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\" & saveAs & ".xls")

                 Set rng = Worksheets(saveAs).UsedRange
             Next olAtt
    End If
```

It wont save the formatted excel file at times during the error, however this rarely happens now and it is only for our own documentation. It now continues through the cycle of client arrays with ease (and actually seems faster). Thank you for the help.